# Obtaining public/external IP Address and importing it into database with ASP.Net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ip, external

Hello I am trying to make a registration page using ASP.Net C# and for a newbie I'm making it pretty good so far. I just encountered this problem, when I try to import the person's IP address into my database during the register, the only successfully attempt gives the database a "::1" value instead of an IP. I have searched all over the web but the only things that I found is the same method, methods that don't work and methods to obtain the local IP of the machine, not the external. Here is my code:

```
string ipaddress;
    ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
        ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

I set the "ipaddress" variable to the query for the database. Can anybody please tell me what's missing/wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"::1" is the IPV6 equivalent of "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 in IPV4. If you run Windows, this is the usual address used to access local machine data. If you deploy your software to a web server that is not capable of driving IPV6 you would see regular IPV4-Addresses.

One note, you should reverse your if statement or use [string.IsNullOrEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid `NullReferenceException`s:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipaddress))
```

For reference to IPV6 please see [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)